# Ubuntu 15.10 | Xserver not starting up | The system is Running on Low graphics mode after playing with NVIDIA drivers | Rewriting xorg.conf

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-geforce, xorg.conf

I am kinda new to linux when it comes to debugging,

I do understand this might just be another repetition, but I've tried out almost every probable solutions out there for a month now, hence new question.

I have ASUS Q550LF with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10 dual boot with integrated Intel HD graphics and Nvidia Geforce [GT 745M] 2GB dedicated graphics.

It all started when I tried installing nvidia drivers from there website and uninstalled nouveau drivers.

So current problem is whenever I boot into Ubuntu, the error comes system is running on low graphics mode. xorg log shows following error

```
[    51.287] 
X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
[    51.288] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    51.288] Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-68-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    51.288] Current Operating System: Linux jitesh 4.3.0-040300-generic #201511020949 SMP Mon Nov 2 14:50:44 UTC 2015 x86_64
[    51.288] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.3.0-040300-generic root=UUID=69910f62-d547-4968-868d-382bd929acff ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    51.288] Build Date: 12 November 2015  05:33:29PM
[    51.288] xorg-server 2:1.17.2-1ubuntu9.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    51.288] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[    51.288]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    51.288] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    51.288] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Feb 25 08:01:58 2016
[    51.288] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    51.288] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    51.289] Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf
    Undefined Screen "nvidia" referenced by ServerLayout "layout".
[    51.289] (EE) Problem parsing the config file
[    51.289] (EE) Error parsing the config file
[    51.290] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    51.290] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    51.290] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    51.290] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    51.290] (EE) 
[    51.290] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

As I see it, my xorg.conf file is being rewritten on every boot, and the rewritten file looks like below:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection
```

I've tried installing, reinstalling, uninstalling nvidia drivers and xserver-xorg, but nothing seems to work.

after installing nvidia-current or bumblebee-nvidia , xconfig sometimes gives error on being able to connect to server saya xorg-xserver is not found in pkg path.

When I try deleting xorg.conf, nvidia-xconfig does creates new xorg.conf, which looks like

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 304.131  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-16)  Sun Nov  8 22:48:17 PST 2015

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

But it's again rewritten to the earlier one with incomplete data.
I tried completely removing nvidia drivers and using default drivers by installing xserver-xorg and other stuff again and again and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop, but nothing seems to work.

I also changed my display manager from lightdm to gdm, but no effect.

Ctrl+Al+f7 always goes into black screen once the lightdm is restarted from tty1

Any help or a pointer will be really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just knew about this, but hopefully.. it can help.

http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/p/prime-indicator/

Prime-Indicator helps you to easily switch from INTEL to NVIDIA or vise versa.

Also, try using nvidia-355 + nvidia-prime these works best.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvida-*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 nvidia-prime
sudo service lightdm restart
```

If your VCARD is not well compatible with nvidia-355, try the lower version.

Another thing, nvidia is sometimes painful for dual-boot (randomly freezes), you might want to add this line to your GRUB (/etc/default/grub)

```
nouveau.modeset=0
```

then reload the grub configuration

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I don't know what just happened here, but hey.. I got my Ubuntu display back.. Thanks a tonne.. I just installed Nvidia-352 and at the end, had to change permissions of .Xauthority . I don't know why they were changed.

Was the issue with nvidia drivers that come with ubuntu? Or it was the issue with not having nvidia-prime ?? also, can I still use bumblebee along with prime? as it's heating up my laptop

Comment: Bumblebee works the same as what nouveau. If you have installed prime, you should have the optimal performance of your VCard.