# Problem during Ubuntu 15.10 boot process

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I might have a problem, which I do not know how to solve:

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my PC, which is equiped with a Nvidia GeForce GTX 980 StriX graphics card.

What happens, when the system boots is, that first I can see the "eggplant" colored starting screen and normally I would also see the Ubuntu logo with the box below it, where I type in my password. But this does not happen.

What happens is, that my computer screen suddenly turns black, then blue with "No HDMI 1 connection", but this can't be, because my screen is linked by HDMI cable with the graphics card of my computer.

Now, what I found out by coincidence is, that when I disconnect the hdmi cable and reconnect it with the computer again, suddenly the startung screen with the Ubuntu logo and the password box appears again, like it was always there. From that point on everything works fine, the computer and the system run normal.

Btw, I already tried the "nomodeset"-thing, as well before installation as after the installation, but that totally messed up everything. After restart I wasn't even able to enter my password in the pw box anymore, because when the Ubuntu starting screen appeared (this time like it should always do), it had a very bad resolution and instead of typing my password inside the pw box, the letters appeared in the left upper corner of my screen and they were white letters on a black background. Oh, and they could be seen, of course, so no "super secret password" anymore.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be and how it can be solved?

There is something I am not sure about:

When I go to System -> Applications and Update -> Additional Drivers, I can choose between two different drivers for my graphics card:

1st: NVIDIA binary driver - version 352.63 used by nvidia (proprietary, tested)

2nd: NVIDIA binary driver - version 352.63 used by nvidia (proprietary)

Currently the X.Org-X-Server-Driver is marked and used.

If you need any more information about the hardware I am using or anything else, please ask what you have to know to give an answer to my problem.

Thank you and best regards

Moe

Btw: I am a Ubuntu beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look on this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738987/ubuntu-15-10-xserver-not-starting-up-the-system-is-running-on-low-graphics-m/738994#738994). Seems like you are encountering the same issue.